# Pandas series - recording numerical changes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panel `dataframe` with many observations on individuals' location data over 10 years. It looks something like this:

```
     personid     location_1991   location_1992  location_1993  location_1994 
0    111          1               1             2              2 
1    233          3               3             4              999  
2    332          1               3             3               3 
3    454          2               2             2               2             
4    567          2               1             1               1
```

I want to track the transitions of each person by creating a variable for each type of transition. I'd like a column to mark whenever a person transitions into each location type. Ideally this would look like:

```
     personid     transition_to_1    transition_to_2   transition_to_3   transition_to_4       
0    111          0                  1                 0                 0 
1    233          0                  0                 0                 1  
2    332          0                  0                 1                 0 
3    454          0                  0                 0                 0             
4    567          1                  0                 0                 0
```

So far, I've tried to iterate through each row, and then loop through each element in the row to check if its the same as the previous one. This seems time intensive. Is there a better way to track the change in values in each row of my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some combination of first stacking those columns, then pivoting along them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_clipboard())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('personid').stack(), columns=['location'])
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df3 = df2.pivot(index='index', columns='location', values='personid')
df3 = df3.fillna(0)
```

So far, it looks like this:

```
location  1    2    3    4    999
index                            
0         111    0    0    0    0
1         111    0    0    0    0
2           0  111    0    0    0
3           0  111    0    0    0
4           0    0  233    0    0
5           0    0  233    0    0
6           0    0    0  233    0
7           0    0    0    0  233
8         332    0    0    0    0
9           0    0  332    0    0
10          0    0  332    0    0
11          0    0  332    0    0
12          0  454    0    0    0
13          0  454    0    0    0
14          0  454    0    0    0
15          0  454    0    0    0
16          0  567    0    0    0
17        567    0    0    0    0
18        567    0    0    0    0
19        567    0    0    0    0

df3['personid'] = df3.max(axis=0, skipna=True)
df3 = df3.set_index('personid', drop=True)
df3[df3 > 0] = 1
```

And there it goes:

```
location  1    2    3    4    999
personid                         
111         1    0    0    0    0
567         1    0    0    0    0
567         0    1    0    0    0
332         0    1    0    0    0
233         0    0    1    0    0
233         0    0    1    0    0
233         0    0    0    1    0
233         0    0    0    0    1
332         1    0    0    0    0
332         0    0    1    0    0
332         0    0    1    0    0
332         0    0    1    0    0
454         0    1    0    0    0
454         0    1    0    0    0
454         0    1    0    0    0
454         0    1    0    0    0
567         0    1    0    0    0
567         1    0    0    0    0
567         1    0    0    0    0
567         1    0    0    0    0
```